# Illegal parameter number in definition of \abx@field@abstract?

Tags: errors

I'm using TexMaker, and today I added one cite that (I think) apparently screwed up my files. This is my document:

```
\documentclass[spanish,11pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Permite acentos y ñ en el código fuente
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
...

\subsubsection{Generación de electrostática}

El método de [...] microesferas \cite{tran2011,brandenberger1999}.
```

And this is the error that I get:

```
(No file specified) Error Line 1615
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \abx@field@abstract.
<to be read again>
x
l.139 ... duras \cite{tran2011,brandenberger1999}.
You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.
```

And this was the cite:

```
@ARTICLE{Brandenberger1999,
  author = {H. Brandenberger and D. Nüssli and V. Piëch and F. Widmer},
  title = {Monodisperse particle production: A method to prevent drop coalescence
    using electrostatic forces },
  journal = {Journal of Electrostatics },

  abstract = {The controlled [...] voltage electrode (400–1400&#xa0;V) is presented (pat. pend.). The droplet [...] beads of 160–800&#xa0;μm [...] },
  }
```

Then I changed all those ü and ë and &#xa0, but it won't get fixed and now I can't compile my files. Please help?? (The [...] stands for regular text)

Comment: Maybe you should start fresh. By that I mean you need to clear out your auxiliary files (like `.aux`, `.bbl`, `.blg`, ...).

Comment: I can't believe it, but I keep struggling with the simplest things. You were absolutely right! Thank you very very much!

Comment: This is because the associated auxiliary file still had the older `&#xa0` content in it, which was inappropriate. And those things are read in *before* updating the files again. So, if the compilation throws an error there, and it doesn't finish, the "corrupt" file will still remain, perpetually throwing the error.

Comment: Excellent, now I'll be aware of this kind of errors. Thank you again!